# Why does u64::trailing_zeros() generate branched assembly when branchless works?

Tags: optimization, rust, x86-64, llvm

This function:

```rust
pub fn g(n: u64) -> u32 {
    n.trailing_zeros()
}
```

generates assembly with a branch:

```
playground::g:
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je  .LBB0_1
    bsfq    %rdi, %rax
    retq

.LBB0_1:
    movl    $64, %eax
    retq
```

This [alternative function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=4f1ec09d6c2d8307a34b43e26232fa75):

```rust
pub fn g(n: u64) -> u32 {
    if n == 0 { u32::MAX } else { n.trailing_zeros() }
}               ^^^^^^^^
```

generates assembly *without* a branch:

```
playground::g:
    bsfq    %rdi, %rcx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpq    $1, %rdi
    sbbl    %eax, %eax
    orl %ecx, %eax
    retq
```

It turns out that the branch gets created only when the constant returned is 64. Returning `0`, or `u32::MAX`, or any other number generates branchless assembly.

Why is this? Just a quirk of the optimizer or there's a reason?

I'm trying to create performant, branchless code.

Using Rust 1.65 release profile

Comment: what is the architecture you're compiling for ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if n == 0 { u64::BITS } else { n.trailing_zeros() }`? this results in a branch.

Comment: @pigeonhands That's because u64::BITS is 64, and as I said, 64 results in a branch.

Comment: This looks like the reason is because `64` is compiled into calling `@llvm.cttz`, and apparently this intrinsic hardcodes the jump, while other numbers generate a `select`.

Comment: If Intel would only document the behaviour of their actual CPUs the way AMD does, it could be `mov $64, %eax` / `bsf %rdi, %rax`.  (Leaving the destination unmodified on input zero.)  But instead Intel unhelpfully documents the destination as undefined in that case.  IDK which Intel CPU ever did anything different, if any, probably not a 64-bit CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`trailing_zeros` corresponds to the [`cttz` LLVM intrinsic](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-cttz-intrinsic).

That intrinsic just so happens to compile to the following instructions on x86-64:

```
g:                                      # @g
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB0_1
        bsf     rax, rdi
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        mov     eax, 64
        ret
```

The output of that intrinsic is the bit width of the integer when the input value is 0. LLVM is able to recognize the redundant operation and remove it, which is why `u64::BITS` or just `64` in your conditional result in the same machine code as just the intrinsic.

It appears that using any other number results in the compiler recognizing the intrinsic branch as dead code, which is therefore removed:

```
e:                                      # @e
        xor     ecx, ecx
        bsf     rax, rdi
        cmove   eax, ecx
        ret
```

Instead, a single conditional move is generated. I believe this variance in output is just a quirk of the LLVM x86-64 assembler when certain intrinsics are involved.

You can reproduce the same discrepancy with C using clang. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zf7rn3cv7)

It might be worth opening an LLVM issue for this, but only if the branchless version is actually better.

[this LLVM issue may be related](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41703)

Comment: Good proof point with clang. Thank you. Not with Rust itself, but with LLVM.

Comment: Also, I don't know which one is better, but assume branchless. How would the branch predictor be able to determine if the numbers I put in will be mostly zero or mostly non-zero?

Comment: Yeah it would make sense, even the smaller code size could produce benefits. And the fact that LLVM uses `cmove` for the other cases makes it seem like that's probably more optional. But I'd recommend on attempting to actually benchmark this if possible.

Comment: @Ana Assuming that branchless code is better is dangerous. The branch predictor can predict if the jump is taken based on the jump address and history, if you call the function with a non-zero argument often enough it will learn that the jump is non-taken. The branchless code always has a `cmovCC` in its critical path, the branched one (if correctly predicted) won't. A naive test with `perf stat` shows that the branched code is 0.5c/iteration faster than the branchless one for a fixed input. I second PitaJ, benchmark it.

Comment: @Ana Usually, when the branch can be predicted the version with branch is slightly faster, but when not the branchless version is much faster.